# Constructor in Child Class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Why is the constructor in `B` required?
IntelliJ suggests to remove `=null` as it is redundant presumably because it is initialized through the given constructor in `A`.
However, this removal (which is presumably also performed by the compiler) then (presumably) requires the constructor in B.

Any other explanation?

```
public abstract class A {
  private Object foo = null;
  public A(Object foo){this.foo=foo;}
}

public class B extends A {
  public B(Object foo){super(foo);}
}
```

Comment: If B doesn't have a constructor, how can you call the parent class constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have "constructor inheritance". The only way  to initialize `A` is to pass the `foo` parameter to its constructor, and the only way to do this is to create a constructor for `B` that does so.

Note, however, that they don't have to have the same signature (like you have in the question) - `B`'s constructor only needs to pass *some* parameter to `A`. E.g.:

```java
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super("Arbitrary default passed to A");
    }

    public B(Object passedToA, Obejct notPassedToA) {
        super(passedToA);
        System.out.println("This argument was not passed to A():" + notPassedToA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the constructor in B required?

If the `class B extends A`, the `class B` must be instantiated in all possible ways as the `class A` can be and the `class B` can have additional ways to be instantiated. It means that `class B` is forced to have a constructor.

The only exemption can be in case of a no-arg constructor because the compiler makes it up with a default constructor i.e. if you put a no-arg constructor in the `class A` the child classes are not forced to have this.

Comment: The need for a constructor in `B` would be the same if  `A` was not `abstract`, so the explanation is somewhat misleading.